# lframConvergence of $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac1{\log(n!)}$

Tags: summation

How do I show that this sum diverges/converges?
 $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac1{\log(n!)}$$

---

I want to use the comparison test, but I do not know how to approach.

Also, Wolfram says this diverges by the comparison test, but Mathematica gives me a numerical answer using the `NSum` function.

Comment: Stirling formula.

Comment: Since $\log n! \sim n\log n$ for large $n$, the sum diverges like $\int_?^n \frac{dx}{x\log x} \sim \log\log n$ for large $n$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** We have $$\log(n!)=\log n+\log(n-1)+\cdots+\log2<\log n+\log n+\cdots\log n<n\log n.$$ Now apply the comparison test and make use of the integral test.